# getWrappedInstance() versus wrappedInstance: property on react-redux @connect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I noticed that there is a property on @connect instance called `wrappedInstance` which has the state of my component wrapped with @connect. If I use this to access state as follows

```
const { contact } = this.datasetConsoleInfo.contact.wrappedInstance.state;
```

It works just fine.

But I was told to use `getWrappedInstance()` since that is what the Docs say to do.

Indeed the following works the exact same:

```
const { contact } = this.datasetConsoleInfo.contact.getWrappedInstance().state;
```

But I am wondering if everyone just does this because this is what the docs say to do and they are afraid of using this nifty property. Maybe the react-redux people added this property to make our lives easier but accidentally documented it poorly.

What is the difference between using `getWrappedInstance()` verses just accessing the `wrappedInstance`: property straight away.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dirrences between wrappedInstance and getWrappedInstance(). But it is not recommended to access directly the property in object (think about [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)))

I assume the codes in `connect` like below.

```
wrappedInstance = /* instance */;

getWrappedInstance() {
  return wrappedInstance;  // just return, but we can protect the data.
}
```

As you know, there is no private variables or methods in javascript. So, actually you can't protect the data even if the data would be provided using only getter. So when we want to protect some data, we have often used the underscore(`_`) to notice that the data is private. (ex, `_wrappedInstance`). Althoght `connect` method didn't use the underscore(`_`), it is good to not access the data directly to adhere Encapsulation.